# Create custom pages Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

My problem: I have a task and I need to create a custom page in CodeIgniter.

### Requirements:

- It is a moderator page which has access to the ADMIN PANEL of the website.
- This moderator page must have the functionality which can create a page in the website.
- The moderator page must have a ckeditor.
- I have to put the content in the database, but i don't know what to do next.

I have an HTML Code stored into the database table, but what I need next, is for me to create a *.PHP* file with the code in it. The problem is that, I do not know how to differentiate the pages and how to keep their links. I also don't know how to load these pages. Is it necessary for me to create a function inside each page?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter has a router file, so let say the route is as follow below

```
 $route['pages/(:any)'] = 'CusomtCtrl/showPages/$1';
```

Now all you have to do is to make the pages/(:any) reference the link that is

example.com/pages/any-dashed-seperated-title

**Or**

it could be the database table id

example.com/pages/table_id equivalent to example.com/pages/1 or example.com/pages/2 and so on

i hope this was helpful, feel free to ask questions.
But i advice understanding and learning before jumping into a cms like application.

Comment: Ezekiel, you propose me to create for each page, a table, which will keep the information about file?

Comment: Ezekiel, i have a database table, with rows: IdPage, ContentOfPage, and how to load each of this pages?

Comment: You don't have to create a table for each page just one page will do, with more columns, such as idpage, pageslug(optional),contentofpage, page_status,createdby,approvedby

Comment: @DanPlaton: Typcically you would have a single table and then a route like Ezekiel has proposed where the `:any` would map to a unique slug in that pages table. You then look up the page based on that slug in your controller and render it appropriately.

Comment: @prodigitalson thank you for the adds in explanation, i hope s/he understands better with your contribution.

Comment: @prodigitalson yes, **i understand that** how to load these pages inside a controller?

Comment: You use the slug to differentiate their links, or assign them to a category and still use slug, you do not necessarily have to create several php files. @DanPlaton having a unique slug title or id will help you more like the table sample i gave in my earlier comment